# How to run multiple django applications on IIS server?

Tags: django, iis, configuration

I am new in django that runs on IIS server. I have manage to set up server that one django application/site is runnging..now I want to add another django application/site to this server. I cant find anywhere the sample web.config how to do that..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".apk" mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".config" mimeType="application/xml" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".pdb" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        </staticContent>

        <handlers>
            <add name="Python FastCGI"
            path="/page1/*"
            verb="*"
            modules="FastCgiModule"
            scriptProcessor="c:\python27\python.exe|c:\python27\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.pyc"
            resourceType="Unspecified"
            requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    
    <appSettings>
        <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="page1.wsgi.application" />
        <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\page1" />
        <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="page1.settings" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>`
```

This is my config so far, how can I add another django site that will be available on URL/page2/ ?

Answer (score 0):

To create a new site click on the server name and add a new website.

enter your site folder path and binding detail.

and copy your old web.config file to the new create site folder and make changes that you want.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".apk" mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".config" mimeType="application/xml" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".pdb" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        </staticContent>

        <handlers>
            <add name="Python FastCGI"
            path="/page2/*"
            verb="*"
            modules="FastCgiModule"
            scriptProcessor="c:\python27\python.exe|c:\python27\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.pyc"
            resourceType="Unspecified"
            requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    
    <appSettings>
        <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="page2.wsgi.application" />
        <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\page2" />
        <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="page1.settings" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Note: use python version after 3.6 with iis if possible.